# spring - quartz - flyway project , flyway does not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, flyway

I am trying to create spring quartz flyway on h2 and I am failing

```
15:58:09.941 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'schedulerFactoryBean'; nested exception is     org.springframework.scheduling.SchedulingException: Could not start Quartz     Scheduler; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure      occured during job recovery. [See nested exception:      org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: Table   "QRTZ_LOCKS" not found; SQL statement:
 SELECT * FROM QRTZ_LOCKS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'schedulerFactoryBean' AND LOCK_NAME = ? FOR UPDATE [42102-193] [See nested exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "QRTZ_LOCKS" not found; SQL statement:
```

this is my properties file :

```
internal.profile=test
    server.port=8080
------
quartz.properties=quartz-inmemory.properties
management.security.enabled=false
flyway.enabled=true
flyway.baseline-version=1
flyway.init-sqls=db/migration/V2_init.sql
flyway.locations=db/migration/V2_init.sql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
flyway.baselineOnMigrate = true
#============================================================================
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties
#============================================================================
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = InMemoryScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO


#============================================================================
# Configure ThreadPool
#============================================================================
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 25
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5


#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore
#============================================================================
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

this is my scheduler :

```
@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean(       @Qualifier("quartzDataSource") DataSource dataSource, JobFactory jobFactory
) throws IOException {
SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
factory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
factory.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties());
return factory;
}
```

Notice , all my scheduler configuration works fine whenever I am trying to do stuff on mysql instance everything works , but on my sql I fail

Comment: Have you read the documentation for flyway.init-sqls and flyway.locations? Neither looks right to me. You also haven't shown any SQL that will actually create the table that is apparently missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it by changing the name of the file to R2_2_init.sql